# css : text hidiing

Tags: css

I am trying to hide the text in a link and make the image visible only and the image click-able.

I am using the code   below but the text doenst seem to hide.

```
<span class="cnn-b">

<a href="http://www.cnn.com" alt="cnn" title="cnn">
<span class="cnn-text">cnn</span>

</a></span> 
css

.cnn-b{
    width: 200px; height: 75px;
    background: url("cnn.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
.cnn-text {
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all the extra markup of `<span>`-s and there is a better ( performance-wise ) way to hide the text than `text-indent: -9999px` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a3JJm/)

***HTML***

```
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" alt="cnn" title="cnn" class="cnn">cnn</a>
```

***CSS***

```css
.cnn {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/75) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing:

`display:block;`

You should use:

> .cnn-text {
>   display:block;
>       text-indent: -9999px; }

Answer (score 0):

You could insert an `<img>` element along with the span, and `display:none;` on the text:

```
<span class="cnn-b">
    <a href="http://www.cnn.com" alt="cnn" title="cnn">
        <span class="cnn-text">cnn</span>
        <img src="cnn.png" />
    </a>
</span>
```

css

```
.cnn-b{
    width: 200px; height: 75px;
}

.cnn-text {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several ways to do what you're talking about.

It sounds like what you're talking about is simply having an image that is clickable.  If that is the case then I would recommend putting the span inside the anchor tag:

```
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" alt="cnn" title="cnn">
<span class="cnn-b"></span>
</a>
```

If you do that, then the only thing you need to worry about is making sure that the image is displayed which can be done by sizing the span in the CSS to the correct width and height and setting the display to block (block will allow it to keep the width):

```
.cnn-b {
    width: 200px; height: 75px;
    background: url("cnn.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/CPUKP/1/

Answer (score 0):

By default a span is an inline element. The width and height property will not work as you intend it on the .cnn-b span. If you change 
`<span class="cnn-b">` to `<div class="cnn-b">` or as suggested by James use `display:block;` on the cnn-b span not the cnn-text span That will solve your problem.
Your final code should be like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .cnn-b{
            display: block;
            width: 200px; height: 75px;
            background: url("cnn.png") no-repeat 0 0;
            text-indent: -9999px;
        }
        .cnn-text {
            text-indent: -9999px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <span class="cnn-b">
        <a href="http://www.cnn.com" alt="cnn" title="cnn">
            <span class="cnn-text">cnn</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```